# Nmap Switches -sSU and -sSV

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to follow along in the nmap book and the author uses a couple of switches -sSU and -sSV, but never explains them. They are in these two search strings:

```
 nmap -F -A -sSU ultra

 nmap -PN -sSV -T4 -F www.amazon.com
```

Does -sSU and -sSV stand for another scan type? I couldn't find these switches in their documentation. I'm guess -sSV has something to do with version detection, but on the -sSU scan, it returned both TCP and UDP ports so I know that one's not just UDP. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nmap's `-s*` options are all "scan types," which basically means features that can be turned on. Any that are not mutually exclusive can be combined. So when you specify `-sSV` you are combining `-sS` ([TCP SYN scan](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html)) with `-sV` ([service and application version detection](https://nmap.org/book/vscan.html)). You can even combine more than two: `-sSUV` will do TCP and UDP port scans and follow them up with version probing.

EDITED TO ADD: "Mutually exclusive" scan types are those that scan the same transport protocol. So all TCP scan types (`-sS`, `-sT`, and the odd `-sAMWFXNI` types) have to be scanned separately. Also, IP Protocol scan (`-sO`) isn't allowed with any other scan types. Some of the odder features like FTP bounce (`-b`) are also probably not able to combine with the others.

Comment: I literally just realized this and was about to type in the answer. Thanks